# Biblatex: replacement of title by a custom entry type under specified conditions

Tags: biblatex

I'm using `biblatex` + Biber for the bibliography of my thesis, but my main reference database is EndNote.  I have over 1400 entries, so I'm not changing it! It's not a major problem, as I can export from EndNote to a `.bib` file in the appropriate format.

I've managed to sort out such things as Unicode characters and Greek letters, but there are still a few things which need tweaking (for example superscripts and subscripts in journal article titles). There are relatively few of these, so what I'd like to do is use a custom field in EndNote (let's call it `latextitle`) to put a version of the journal article title with LaTeX tweaks (e.g. `\textsuperscript`, `\textsubscript`). So finally I arrive at my question: Is there any way I can get `biblatex` to substitute the `latextitle` field for the `title` field if the `latextitle` field is not blank?

I appreciate this is rather a 'local' question, so I'm fully prepared to be slapped down!

Comment: That should actually be a straightforward sourcemapping job with Biber. Somewhere along the lines of `\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=latextitle, final]
      \step[fieldset=title, origfieldval]
    }
  }
}` (modulo line breaks, of course) if the memory serves right.

Comment: That works beautifully @moewe! You also correctly spotted that I meant 'title' when I said 'journaltitle' – I've now amended that in the original post. If you want to formalise your answer I can formally accept it.

Comment: Glad it works, to be honest, I just assumed you meant `title` and did not even properly realise you had written `journaltitle` in your post. But, of course, I'd like to think it was my precognitive abilities leading me the right way `;-)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously, it would be best to have a properly formatted `.bib` file, i.e. one that `biblatex` and Biber can actually process without choking.
But in some cases that's not really possible (or even desirable).

Using Biber it is very easy to modify a source file on the fly.

In your case, where you propose to have a `latextitle` field for consumption for LaTeX/`biblatex` and the "normal" `title` field, one can use the following straightforward mapping

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=latextitle, final]
      \step[fieldset=title, origfieldval]
    }
  }
}
```

It maps an existing `latextitle` to `title` overwriting the latter, and does nothing if `latextitle` does not exist.

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test,
  author = {Arnold Uthor},
  title  = {Uhh. LaTeX won't like \this},
  latextitle = {But we're fine here},
  journal = {Journal of Confusing TeX},
  date    = {2014-10-10},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=latextitle, final]
      \step[fieldset=title, origfieldval]
    }
  }
}

\nocite{test,wilde} 

\begin{document}
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks again @moewe. It really is a very elegant solution for what I need. Once the latextitle fields in EndNote are populated (and I will do this as I add citations to the database in future, if appropriate), it's a matter of seconds to export my entire database of 1400+ entries direct to (and to overwite) my .bib file. The tricky bit was to get EndNote to export the data in a .bib format!